# Are all uncaught exceptions fatal in PHP?

Tags: php, exception

While studying for the Zend PHP Exam I came across the following contradicting information:

From the Zend PHP 5.3 Study guide v1a - PDF available [here](http://downloads.zend.com/guides/php5.3/PHP_5-3_Study_Guide_v1a.pdf).

[image]

The answer:

[image]

And information from the php Architect's Zend PHP 5 Certification Study Guide by Davey Shafik
ISBN: 0-9738621-4-9 Page 128
[image]

Can someone tell me which one is true?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), please note the `unless`.

> If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with
>   an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined
>   with set_exception_handler().

Comment: So, I'd say they are both correct. If you don't *catch* it (with catch statement), and you don't *handle* it (with `set_exception_handler()`) then it becomes fatal.

Comment: I don't agree. Execution will ALWAYS stop even if you use exception handler. It won't just show error message but this is fatal error. So in my opinion the question is bad formulated.

Answer (score 2):

Uncaught exceptions almost always cause a fatal error, unless `set_exception_handler()` is used. That's what it's not **always** but ***Almost* Always**.

From the PHP manual:

> If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined with set_exception_handler().